# Working with two UITables in a view: how to auto scroll one when the other is scrolled by the user?

Tags: ios, uitableview, autoscroll

So this is the situation:

I will have 2 differente UITables in the same controller. So, i want to work with a classic vertical UITable controlled by the user who scrolls up and down as demanded. Meanwhile, in the same view I want to have a second UITable with horizontal layout.

Is it possible to auto scroll the horizontal table at the same time when the user scrolls with his finger the vertical UITable?

Comment: this is not easy to do considering it's not build in to the ios sdk to do  two separate gestures at the same time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UITableView` extends `UIScrollView`. Implement the appropriate scroll view delegate methods to be notified of changes to the content offset of the table view. Based on the updated value of the table you can update the content offset of the other table.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what i needed. With some amount of work and working with the delegate methods of the tables could notify one table when the other finishes it scrolling action.